# Visual Basic counting positions of a substring within a string

Tags: vb.net, string, substring, counting, basic

So I am trying to make a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio using Visual Basic that has a textbox where you input a sentence, another textbox where you can input a word that is in that sentence, then a button that when it is clicked the position(s) of the word entered in the sentence are outputted onto a label. At the moment the code counts the occurrences of a word but I want to adapt it so it counts the positions that word occurs in instead (eg In "Hello hello hello" "hello" is entered and 1 2 3 is outputted.

Current code is below any help will be appreciated thanks.

```
Public Class Form1
    'first attempt not working
    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim input As String = textBox1.Text
        Dim word As String = textBox2.Text
        Dim occurrences As Integer = 0

        Dim intCursor As Integer = 0
        Do Until intCursor >= input.Length
            Dim strCheckThisString As String = Mid(LCase(input), intCursor + 1, (Len(input) - intCursor))

            Dim intPlaceOfWord As Integer = In-Str(strCheckThisString, word)
            If intPlaceOfWord > 0 Then
                occurrences += 1
                intCursor += (intPlaceOfWord + Len(word) - 1)
            Else
                intCursor = input.Length
            End If
        Loop
        Positions.text = occurrences
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Look at String.IndexOf, specifically this overload https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the words are always separated by spaces, you could first split the string into an array of words

```
Dim positions = New List(Of Integer)()
Dim words As String() = input.Split()
For i As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
    If words(i).ToLower() = "hello" Then
        positions.Add(i + 1)
    End If
Next
```

Now the list `positions` contains the positions of the hello-words within the sentence.

The [String.Split method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) has overloads allowing you to specify other delimiters like commas, for instance. There is also an option to remove empty entries.

Comment: So I tried adapting my code from this but I keep getting the message System.Collections.Generic.List’1(System.Int32) appearing on my label where the positions should be outputted. Any idea why?

Comment: Public Class Form1

    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

Comment: Dim input As String = textBox1.Text
        Dim word As String = textBox2.Text

        Dim positionsword = New List(Of Integer)()
        Dim words As String() = input.Split()
        For i As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
            If words(i).ToLower() = textBox2.Text Then
                positionsword.Add(i + 1)
            End If
        Next


        Positions.Text = positionsword.ToString

    End Sub
End Class

Comment: `positionsword` is a list and its To|String method just outputs its type name. You must use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to convert to contents of the list into a string.